# Cache non static url with service worker

Tags: javascript, regex, service-worker, workbox

I have a little problem with the regex in workbox (my service worker).
I need to cache a respond of my api and this respond is an image.
For that I need to request an url like this: https://myapi/image/12

So I can't inculud a specifique path in my service worker and I need to deal with regex I guess.
I tried this:

```
                   urlPattern: new RegExp('\/image/'),
                handler: 'NetworkFirst',
                options: {
                    networkTimeoutSeconds: 15,
                    cacheName: 'Saved bill img',
                    expiration: {
                      maxEntries: 25,
                      maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60,
                    },
                }
```

but It doesn't work, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I should ask was how to define the beginning of a query in a regex. And so their is a lot of answer on that. So this is what I've done:

```
new RegExp('^https:\/\/myapi\/image/')
```

Comment: You can always edit the original question to add more info (:

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version of Workbox are you using, but the sample code doesn't match a version known to me.

The [Common Recipes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes) page shows this syntax for the current version (5.1.3):

```
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {StaleWhileRevalidate} from 'workbox-strategies';

registerRoute(/\/some\/path\/some-file\.txt$/,
  new StaleWhileRevalidate()
);
```

The regexes you're using have an unescaped final slash. You can always try the regexes on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) first.

To further exemplify, the regex `^https:\/\/example\.com\/image\/` will match all the requests whose URL begins with `https://example.com/image/`. You can use any of these variants in JavaScript:

- `new RegExp('^https:\/\/example\.com\/image\/')`
- `/^https:\/\/example\.com\/image\//`